# Auto transition of containers in flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, mxml

for example I have a container:

```
<mx:HBox width="100">
   <mx:Box width="50">
   </mx:Box>
   <mx:Box width="50">
   </mx:Box>
   <mx:Box width="50">
   </mx:Box>
</mx:HBox>
```

the parent container have a width of 100, and the children containers are obviusly bigger, well then appears the scrollbar that can be disabled/enabled, but I want the third block to jump down, i mean 2 box in a line each 50 * 2 = 100, but I can't realize that, also i've tried the same with `<s:HGroup>`, is that possible to do?

right now I am forced to do this:

```
<mx:VBox width="100">

   <mx:HBox>
      <mx:Box width="50">
      </mx:Box>
      <mx:Box width="50">
      </mx:Box>
   </mx:HBox>

    <mx:HBox>
       <mx:Box width="50">
       </mx:Box>
    </mx:HBox>

</mx:VBox>
```

Comment: If it doesn't have to be entirely fluid, you can use `TileLayout` (I believe there's a `TileGroup` too - a Group with a TileLayout), otherwise I think you'll have to write a custom Layout.

Comment: solution found, is the <s:TileGroup>, thank you!